# Custom sorting by type and order of objects and return a list of lists

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, data-structures

Here is the problem I am facing to sort some objects by type and given order.
So, I have few types of object: say t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7.
and few slots: say slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5.
I am given an array of objects in some particular order.

My objective is to return an array of slots filled with objects which meet following conditions:

- slot1: Can hold multiple objects. Only objects of type t1 can go here
- slot2: Can hold multiple objects. Only objects of type t2 can go here
- slot3: Can hold only 1 object. Objects of type t3 can go here. But if there is no t3 object, we retrieve an object of type t4. If there is no object of type t4, we retrieve from t5, and so on. Also, if there are multiple objects of same type, we take the first from the input array.
- slot4: Can hold only 1 object. Objects of type t4 can go here. But if there is no t4 object, we retrieve an object of type t5. If there is no object of type t5, we retrieve from t6, and so on. Also, if there are multiple objects of same type, we take the first from the input array.
- slot5: Can hold only 1 object. Objects of type t5 can go here. But if there is no t5 object, we retrieve an object of type t6. If there is no object of type t6, we retrieve from t7, and so on. Also, if there are multiple objects of same type, we take the first from the input array.
- and so on...

So, for above condition if I had 5 input objects: object1, object2, object3, object4, object5 and 4 slots: slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4.
where,

- object1 - t1
- object2 - t3
- object3 - t5
- object4 - t5
- object5 - t6
- object6 - t1

The output would be:

- slot1 will contain object1, object6
- slot2 will contain null
- slot3 will contain object2
- slot4 will contain object3

I hope that is clear. I understand that Slot1 and Slot2 are special. From slot 3, all other slots follow similar condition.

I am trying to write a function to return an array of slots with filled objects. At the same time I want to organize this in a good design - something like having a config which has some way of determining what types goes in which slots and defining the type of object.

What I have tried so far:

```
class MyObject 
{
  String type;
}

class Slot
{
  int capacity;
  MyObject[] canContain;
}

class MyProject
{
  Slot Slot1 = new Slot { capacity: 100, canContain: {"type1"}) 
  Slot Slot2 = new Slot { capacity: 100, canContain: {"type2"}) 
  Slot Slot3 = new Slot { capacity: 1, canContain: {"type3", "type4"}) 
  Slot Slot4 = new Slot { capacity: 1, canContain: {"type4", "type5"}) 

  void getSlots(MyObject[] objects) 
  {
     // I would end up using multiple for loops here for each slot
     // not sure if that is the right approach
     // if it is, just let me know and I could proceed
     // if not, is there another good way of approaching this
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Preferred language: C# or Java.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to us an array for this? If you want to hold a bunch of different things in different amounts, you really should think about making a custom data type.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by custom data type. I am already using 2 classes for Object and Slot. Will those not suffice? I don't want the code. Just a basic idea on what would be the right approach would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas to continue on your design :

If you know the different type of objects, use an enum to define it.
The logic of processing can be in one class, and use a data structure like :

```
Map<ItemType, List<Slot>> slots = new HashMap<>();
```

For each item you need to store, the processing will find the slots in which it can be stored by getting the map by object type. 
The `List<Slot>` can handle both rules for slots in a generic way : 
The list contains the slots in which an object of a given type can be stored. You can implement the priority-list slots with a `LinkedList` - if a slot capacity is reached, peek the next in the list, etc.
When the list of slots contains only one slot, this handle the case where a slot can only handle objects of the same type.

Comment: Thanks Abbe! That definitely is much cleaner and a good approach. I will try that out.